# Android Firebase login and register app crashes even if code is right. what's the solution for this

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to Android. I had copied this code from Internet. This code was running previously. But now the app crashes. [this shows up after clicking register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWXIg.jpg) Don't got the reason exactly why it crashes. I'm working on a login register kinda app using Firebase on Android Studio. It builds just fine, but when I run it on my phone, the launcher activity works but the problem occurs when I use my button to access my Firebase login activity.  How do I resolve the crash?

Java file.

```
package com.example.omkar.smileservices;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class signup extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private EditText inputName,inputEmail, inputPassword, inputConfirmPassword;
private Button btnRegister, btnSignIn;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        //profile activity
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(signup.this,home.class));
    }

    progressDialog =new ProgressDialog(this);

    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
    btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signin);
    inputName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    inputConfirmPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.conpassw);

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.signin:
            startActivity(new Intent(signup.this,login.class));
            break;
        case R.id.register:
            register();
            break;
    }
}

public void register(){
    String name = inputName.getText().toString().trim();
    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    String confirmpassword = inputConfirmPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter valid email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(confirmpassword)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (password.length() < 6) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if(!confirmpassword.matches(password)){
        inputConfirmPassword.setError("Doesn't match the Password.");
        inputConfirmPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering..");
    progressDialog.show();

    //create user
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(signup.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(signup.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                       // progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Unable to Register. Please try Later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                       // progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Registered Successfully..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(signup.this, home.class);
                        finish();
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });

}
}
```

Crash log

```
03-28 13:19:30.498 24522-24540/com.example.omkar.smileservices D/FA: Logging 
event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, 
firebase_previous_class(_pc)=login, 
firebase_previous_id(_pi)=9003268579764646367, 
firebase_screen_class(_sc)=signup, 
firebase_screen_id(_si)=9003268579764646368}]
03-28 13:19:54.733 24522-24522/com.example.omkar.smileservices 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.omkar.smileservices, PID: 24522

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.omkar.smileservices.signup.register(signup.java:75)
                                                                                 at com.example.omkar.smileservices.signup.onClick(signup.java:68)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Put your crash log

Comment: "This code was running previously. [AND what happened here???] But now the app crashes."

Comment: I wanted to add the login details to Firebase Database. So i had made changes. But now I have rolled back to previous code.

Comment: Check to make sure that id's defined for all EditTextview in the layout xml matches to what is used for findViewById calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash is caused by a NullPointerException and most likely by the following line:

```
inputName.getText().toString().trim();
```

As the error in logs says:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method  `EditText.getText()` on a null
>   object reference

It is clear that the null object reference is `inputName`, which should point to your editText in the XML layout. 
Therefore, in the following line

```
 inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
```

`findViewById` method did not bind successfully a view to your EditText (view) variable called `inputName`.

As suggested in the comments, you can solve this by checking that the XML layout file that you have set (which is activity_signup.xml) contains an EditText with the id `name`.